What are the hidden achievements in Dredge?
I noticed while playing Dredge on Steam that there are 14 hidden achievements that I've not yet gotten. What are the secret achievements in Dredge and how do I unlock them?

Looking at global achievements there should be an option to click on hidden achievements, showing you the achievement with its description revealed

According to Dot Esports, there are 17 hidden achievements in the Steam version (apparently the console version only has 14)
Here are they and their descriptions:



    From the Fog — Honk your horn at a ghost at night




    Perfect Packing — Fill every inventory slot




    Cruel Heat — Maintain 50-percent haste for ten seconds




    Dimensional Bypass — Travel a far distance using manifest




    Banisher — Banish ten threats during the nighttime




    Unsustainable Fishing — Use Atrophy to spot a fishing spot from a far distance




    Feeling prepared — Fill every equipment slot in your inventory




    Mixed Results — Use different bait to catch three different types of fish in one fishing spot




    Prey Sighted — Use your telescope to see a fish of each type




    Safe Havens — Go to every dock in the game




    Unwanted — Toss 25 fish




    The Secret — Surrender the Music Box




    The Bond — Entrust the Ring




    The Chains — Relinquish the Necklace




    The Moment — Give up the Pocketwatch




    Unshackled — Find a use for the Relics




    Sated — Throw it back



